# Javascript window.print() method only works once

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code snippet I have implemented on some Angular project in one of the components. I can print successfully but when I try the second time the `onClickPrint()` method is not triggered. What am I missing?

```
  onClickPrint() {
    const printContents = document.getElementById('permit').innerHTML;
    const originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    // document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    window.close();
  }


<button mat-button (click)="onClickPrint()" class="my-btn">Print licence</button>

<mat-card size="B4" class=" container w-100  bg" id="permit">

...

</mat-card>
```

When I inspect the button...

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are closing the window where the elements you are trying to get live. Removing `window.close()` should work.

Comment: You need to remove the print element from the DOM in order to use print() again.

Comment: @Rager I initially removed it but there was no effect when I try to click anywhere else like on the sidebar menus I can't.

Comment: You are modifying the DOM directly. This is throwing angular off and breaking your entire app.

Comment: @shadowfox476 I've implemented as suggested below but upon navigating to the print detail component the page to be printed is blank.

Comment: You probably should open a new question with as many details about the new component you made. My suggestion was fairly open ended leaving you to set up the route, service, and component. I wouldn't be able to say why it's blank without knowing more details. As for actually printing, this should be no different than printing a standard webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are modifying the DOM directly with this code:

```
const printContents = document.getElementById('permit').innerHTML;
const originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
```

Doing so breaks all the references and things I can't begin to comprehend.

Why not have a separate component and route that contains what you want to print, then run print on that component after it loads up.

**For example:**

```
onClickPrint() {
    this.router.navigate(['/print-details']);
}
```

In a small service maintain the details that need to be printed:

```
class DetailService {
    public details;
}
```

In your print component

```
class PrintComponent implements AfterViewInit  {       
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.detailService.details; 
        // Finish out your component template view or whatever you need to do
        window.print();
    }
}
```

When working in Angular, try to let angular do all the heavily lifting with the DOM. If you absolutely have to modify it, there is a class, Render2 that can help, but its a last resort. https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `window.close()`, for you to print the window again you must have a window open.

Possible solution:

- Remove the line where you close the window

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before.

I found opening a new window to print will fix your problem, you can either pass your styles via link or a style tag(note: you will have errors if you're using angular materials, so style in plain css, but you shouldn't have problems with mat-card, becouse the id tag is on it).

You will also notice i'm using jquery, becouse mainly Mac and IOS can tend to bug out and not show the print window in all it's entirety.

```
onClickPrint() {
    let popupWinindow
    let innerContents = document.getElementById('permit').innerHTML;
    popupWinindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800px,height=600px,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no');
    popupWinindow.document.open();
    popupWinindow.document.write(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
        <title>File Name</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          window.onload = function() {
            setTimeout(() => {
              window.print();
            }, 1000);      
          };
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        ${innerContents}
      </body>
    </html>
    `);
    popupWinindow.document.close();
  }
```